# Doctor Who: The Complete Sixth Series, who wants it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, promotional-grant

The release of **Doctor Who: The Complete Sixth Series** gives us an opportunity to expand the site's [Doctor Who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who) content.

So I propose:

- 5 users with *the highest-rep users of the month* at the time of grant's end (which can be viewed by clicking on the "users" and then "month" tab on the main page) will receive a copy of **Doctor Who: The Complete Sixth Series** on either Blu-Ray or DVD. **Note** that this is the first time we are not going by all-time rep. Hopefully this will spread the grant around to newer, highly involved users!
- The recipients will be encouraged to **ask thoughtful questions** about Series 6 of Doctor Who in general and/or the show in particular. These same users (as well as all of our users) are encouraged to be "on call" and ready to answer any related questions that pop up about Doctor Who. Blogging would also be encouraged.

**Note** that users who ask for Blu-Rays must have the capability to play Blu-Ray discs; Stack Exchange will not provide a Blu-Ray player. Same goes for DVD players, guys. Same for DVD players.

Please answer below with your **username** and if you **prefer Blu-Ray or DVD**.

The recipients will be chosen on **Monday, November 21st at 4:00 PM EST/21:00 UTC**.

Comment: I like the idea of using monthly reputation. As much as I like getting lots of free stuff, let's spread things out a bit;-) It's much harder to maintain high rankings in the month than all time...

Answer (score 4):

Congrats to the four users who will be receiving Doctor Who: The Complete Sixth Series:

- thedaian
- Kalamane
- Keen
- DavRob60

Hurray!

Comment: You asked for five users, you got four. Still looking for one more?

Comment: A late user coming pass the deadline, I think [I saw this before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/936/45), I declare this the first official meta.scifi meme.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my low rep self into this grant, and asking for the DVD version (don't yet have a proper blu-ray player, don't know when I'll be getting one...)

If I get this grant, I promise to carry around a felt marker.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a blu-ray.

*Come along, Pond.*

Note for Brett: If I get this, don't send it to the address you have for me on file, as that's my work address, where I won't be next week.  I'll send you my home address.

Answer (score 0):

DavRob60, I will prefer the Blu-Ray.

I think I had my share of grand and I don't want to abuse, **So I will resign my grant if (and only if) there's more than 5 interested user.**

Answer (score 0):

Kalamane,  I'm throwing my hat into the ring.  I'd prefer a DVD.